# scalajs-bundler does not create the *-fastopt-bundler.js.map" as value

Tags: sbt, scala.js, scalajs-bundler

When running `val bundle = (Compile / fastOptJS / webpack).value` in my `build.sbt`, I get the following files in the 'bundle':

[image: sources]

What I am missing is the `-fastopt-bundler.js.map`.

If I check `target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main` the file is there!

The only setting of my `build.sbt` is:

`webpackBundlingMode := BundlingMode.LibraryAndApplication()`

Comment: Do you see a line saying “Bundling dependencies with source maps” in the console?

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy: Yes, after `Fast optimizing`

Comment: Only one file is expected to be generated by the `LibraryAndApplication` mode. It is not clear to me why it is named `-fastopt-library.js.map` instead of `-fastopt-bundle.js.map`. What does the `sourceMappingURL` link point to, in your `-fastopt-bundle.js.map` file?

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy: the only thing that is referenced is at the end of `-fastopt-bundle.js.map`: `"file":"scala-js-tutorial-fastopt-bundle.js"}`

Comment: Sorry, I meant at the end of your `-fastopt-bundle.js` file.

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy: `//# sourceMappingURL=scala-js-tutorial-fastopt.js.map
/n
//# sourceMappingURL=scala-js-tutorial-fastopt-bundle.js.map`

Comment: Then, something is probably wrong, can you please report your problem here? https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/issues/new

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy Ok - thanks - See https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/issues/290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open issue with *scalajs-bundler* Plugin:

https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/issues/290